# Creating Emojis Discord.Py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    with open("emoji.jpg", "r") as emoji:
      image = emoji.read()
    await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name='user', image=image, roles=None, reason=None)
```

I'm trying to create a command that takes a file and makes it an emoji. I'm keep getting the error 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 249: character maps to '. emoji.jpg is in the same folder that my bot file is in. I can't find an answer anywhere, I even check the docs but can't find anything on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("emoji.jpg", "rb") as emoji:
    image = emoji.read()
await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name='user', image=image, roles=None, reason=None)
```